# Boost preprocessor: Sample not working

Tags: c++, boost, boost-preprocessor

I tried to compile a sample from the [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) library which is:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/insert.hpp>
#define SEQ (a)(b)(d)
BOOST_PP_SEQ_INSERT(SEQ, 2, c) // expands to (a)(b)(c)(d)
```

on Visual Studio 2008 and I get the error `error C2065: 'b' : undeclared identifier`

Is there a problem with the sample or am I missing something??

Please note: The sequence definition itself is ok. To show this, I compiled this code:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each.hpp>

#define SEQ (w)(x)

#define MACRO(r, data, elem) BOOST_PP_CAT(elem, data)

struct w_
{
 int x;
};
void test()
{
 BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(MACRO, _, SEQ);
    x_.x = 3;
}
```

DISCLAIMER: this code is WTF code, and I never intended to use BOOST PP like this :-)

Comment: So, which code produces the quoted error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are trying to compile a source file containing:

```
(a)(b)(c)(d)
```

I suppose you should either put this in a context where this code makes sense, or just run the preprocessor (without compiling the result).

Comment: I don't think this is true, see my Edit

Comment: @Philip: If you take the three line file (boost's sample) and *compile* it, the preprocessor will turn it into `(a)(b)(c)(d)` and then the compiler comes along and makes no sense out of it. That code is not supposed to do anything on its own.